# How to drag a scene in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, drag-and-drop, draggable, mousemove

When I drag the mouse left or right, i'd like drag the scene, don't rotate camera.

I tried

```
camera.position.x = mouseX;  
camera.position.y = mouseY;
```

but scene rotated

I tried change position in scene — scene rotated.

How to drag the scene?

Comment: I'm now trying to move the group items but not scene... It works if don't use zoom. Сalculate the coefficient should ... but I think there is a solution in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a file i got at [github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1535) that might work

```
 THREE.DragControls = function(_camera, _objects, _domElement) {

 if (_objects instanceof THREE.Scene) {

_objects = _objects.children;

 }

 var _projector = new THREE.Projector();

 var _mouse = new THREE.Vector3(),

    _offset = new THREE.Vector3();

var _selected;

_domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

_domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

_domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);


function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

   _mouse.x = (event.clientX / _domElement.width) * 2 - 1;

   _mouse.y = -(event.clientY / _domElement.height) * 2 + 1;

    var ray = _projector.pickingRay(_mouse, _camera);

    if (_selected) {

         var targetPos = ray.direction.clone().multiplyScalar(_selected.distance).addSelf(ray.origin);

         _selected.object.position.copy(targetPos.subSelf(_offset));

        return;

   }


    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(_objects);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

       _domElement.style.cursor = 'pointer';

    } else {

        _domElement.style.cursor = 'auto';

    }

  }

   function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

     event.preventDefault();

     _mouse.x = (event.clientX / _domElement.width) * 2 - 1;

     _mouse.y = -(event.clientY / _domElement.height) * 2 + 1;

     var ray = _projector.pickingRay(_mouse, _camera);

     var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(_objects);

     if (intersects.length > 0) {

         _selected = intersects[0];

         _offset.copy(_selected.point).subSelf(_selected.object.position);

         _domElement.style.cursor = 'move';
   }        
  }


  function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {

     event.preventDefault();

     if (_selected) {

         _selected = null;

    }

     _domElement.style.cursor = 'auto';

 }

  }
```

Comment: there seems to be a few iteration of this code on the site - the link is worth checking out

Answer (score 2):

You can try using (after you define your camera)

```
controls = new THREE.RollControls(camera);
controls.movementSpeed = 10;
controls.lookSpeed = 1;
controls.rollSpeed = 0;
controls.autoForward = false;
```

after including this in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="three.js/examples/js/controls/RollControls.js"></script>
```

In addition you would have to change your onWindowResize event to add

```
controls.handleResize();
```

and your render() function to add

```
controls.update(clock.getDelta());
```

and your init() function to add

```
clock = new THREE.Clock();
```